# infinispan client HOTROD massive put data ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request

Tags: java, caching, datagrid, infinispan, hot-rod

I found other responses to the issue, but I would want to explain my use case if someone have the configuration solutions side or in other case is the Distribuited Cache service limit.

**DATA GRID Server** *8.2.3* in a cluster 4 VM with the followed config

```
{
      "distributed-cache": {
        "mode": "SYNC",
        "remote-timeout": 17500,
        "state-transfer": {
          "timeout": 60000
        },
        "encoding": {
          "key": {
            "media-type": "text/plain"
          },
          "value": {
            "media-type": "application/x-protostream"
          }
        },
        "locking": {
          "concurrency-level": 1000,
          "acquire-timeout": 15000,
          "striping": false
        },
        "statistics": true
      }
    }
```

Application side **client HOT-ROD** version with standard Jcache lib version*12.1.11.Final-redhat-00001*

```
@PostConstruct
  private void setUp() {
      LOGGER.info("START [setUp] CACHE");
     
      File conf = new File(System.getenv("CLIENT_HOTROD_FILE_PATH"));
     
      URI uri = conf.toURI();
    
      // Retrieve the system wide cache manager via org.infinispan.jcache.remote.JCachingProvider
      javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider("org.infinispan.jcache.remote.JCachingProvider")
            .getCacheManager(uri, this.getClass().getClassLoader(), null);
      
      this.cache = cacheManager.getCache(DATAGRIDKEY);
     
      LOGGER.info("END [setUp] cache " + this.cache.getName() );
  }
```

The client config is default.

My test performed is the: **Massive put data on distribuited Cache infinispan on the cluster**
Frequently the app receive the responses timeout from the server as followed:

```
[1/26/22 14:58:02:767 CET] 00001ffd HOTROD W org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.protocol.Codec20 checkForErrorsInResponseStatus ISPN004005: Error received from the server: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 1770 from DM10RH08
```

Is there the way to optimize the performance server side and client side via configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue changing the server Data grid configuration

distributed-cache from **SYNC** to **ASYNC** mode.

The exceeding remote-timeout server side was caused from the time spent for Sync replication key in subset nodes of the cluster Data Grid.

From the Data Grid document ( [doc SYNC and ASYNC replication](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/6.6/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-synchronous_and_asynchronous_replication) ):

> **Replication mode can be synchronous or asynchronous depending on the
> problem being addressed.**
>
> Synchronous replication blocks a thread or caller (for example on a
> put() operation) until the modifications are replicated across all
> nodes in the cluster. By waiting for acknowledgments, synchronous
> replication ensures that all replications are successfully applied
> before the operation is concluded.
>
> Asynchronous replication operates significantly faster than
> synchronous replication because it does not need to wait for responses
> from nodes. Asynchronous replication performs the replication in the
> background and the call returns immediately. Errors that occur during
> asynchronous replication are written to a log. As a result, a
> transaction can be successfully completed despite the fact that
> replication of the transaction may not have succeeded on all the cache
> instances in the cluster.

My last server conf:

```
{
  "distributed-cache": {
    "mode": "ASYNC",
    "remote-timeout": 17500,
    "state-transfer": {
      "timeout": 60000
    },
    "encoding": {
      "key": {
        "media-type": "text/plain"
      },
      "value": {
        "media-type": "application/x-protostream"
      }
    },
    "locking": {
      "concurrency-level": 1000,
      "acquire-timeout": 15000,
      "striping": false
    },
    "statistics": true
  }
}
```

Furthermore always in server conf ( /opt/redhat/redhat-datagrid-8.2-server/bin/server.conf )

I set *Xms* the same size of *Xmx* to avoid the performance degradation when the GC starts up.

I found performance tuning link: [performance tuning cache link](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/tuning/tuning.html)